# how to modify a constraint in sql plus?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have created a table as follows:

```
create table emp( emp_id number(5) primary key
                , emp_name varchar(20) not null
                , dob date );
```

After the table has been created how would I change the constraint `not null` to `unique` or any other constraint in SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 3):

You don't change a constraint from one type to another.  You can add a unique constraint to the table

```
ALTER TABLE emp 
  ADD ( COSTRAINT uk_emp_name UNIQUE( emp_name ) );
```

That is independent of whether `emp_name` is allowed to have `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ALTER TABLE` command. For details look here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm#i2103817

Answer (score 0):

We cant be able to modify the already added constraint. Just we have to drop the constraint and add the new one with the same name, but add it with the necessary changes.

```
ALTER TABLE  table_name drop constraint contraint_name;

alter table tablename add constraint containt_name CHECK (column_name IN (changes in the contraint)) ENABLE;
```